# How to redirect to a page in another folder?

Tags: asp.net

This is a rather simple question but i'm a bit confused about it:

My solution contains **Folders A & Folder B** 
**FolderA** contains aspx **pages 1 & 2** 
**FolderB** contains aspx **pages 3 & 4**

**From Page 2** I need to **open page 4**

I've tried using the following: `"~/FolderB/Page4.aspx`" but this didn't work and was translated as "`/FolderA/~/FolderB/Page4.aspx`" which doesn't exist.

What is the correct path to Page4 from Page2 ?

Comment: add site path in config file then use it to make link.

Comment: @Sain Pradeep: Thank you, another user had suggested a solution in the comment and it worked for me, not sure why he deleted it. 
The working solution : "../FolderB/Page4.aspx"

Comment: it may cause problem to use "../" in url

Comment: Well, I've tested it and it worked fine. Can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 2):

The working solution : "../FolderB/Page4.aspx"